# SQL Server Stored Procedure SET Options

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What are the best SET Options to issue before stored procedure creation?

for example

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS  ON 

CREATE PROCEDURE HelloWorld
AS
    --also, should any be issued within the procedure body?
    PRINT 'hello world!'
    RETURN 0
GO
```

By best, I mean the most preferred settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **stored procedure creation** specifically, then only two are important at *parse time*

```
SET ANSI_NULLS
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
```

And they should be **ON** to work with newer SQL Server functionality that only works these being ON

> Stored procedures execute with the SET settings specified at execute time except for SET ANSI_NULLS and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER. Stored procedures specifying SET ANSI_NULLS or SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER use the setting specified at stored procedure creation time. If used inside a stored procedure, any SET setting is ignored.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx

To set both at the same time and others as well, use

```
SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON
```

When enabled (ON), this option enables the following ISO settings:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS
SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS
SET ANSI_PADDING
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
SET ANSI_WARNINGS
```

For completeness, set these other three at the connection level which allows things like INDEXED VIEWs to work correctly

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Transaction Isolation Level (often Read committed - to ensure no dirty reads). And unless you're interested in the number of rows affected; set nocount on

Answer (score -3):

I typically don't bother setting any before the proc.  In the proc Itypically use `SET NOCOUNT ON` and if it is just a select `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`

Comment: Read uncommitted should be used with caution. If it's a Stored Procedure it most likely does not want to do a dirty read of any data.

Comment: Why not? If all I'm doing is pulling data, why do I want to lock the entire table? Being able to do a dirty read is very important if running a large query against a production database.  Sure, large queries should be run against a reporting database, but when someone in upper management wants to run a daily activity report at noon, what else are you going to do?  Lock the database so they can run their report?